# How to make aliases sql queries with certain criteria

Tags: mysql

I Have wrote sql query something like this :

```
SELECT `petugas_input`, 
COUNT(`petugas_input`) AS `01-MAR`,
COUNT(`petugas_input`) AS `02-MAR`,
COUNT(`petugas_input`) AS `03-MAR`
FROM `tabel_arsip`
WHERE `tgl_input_arsip`>='2016-03-01 00:00:00' AND `tgl_input_arsip`<='2016-03-01 23:59:59'
GROUP BY `petugas_input`
```

and its generate result like this

[image: sample_table]

My question is how to add criteria to the aliases column so that it will show different value on different date. (not the same value in the date column as above)

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to rely on a little complex grouping:

```
SELECT 
    `petugas_input`, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN DATE(tgl_input_arsip) = '2016-03-01' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `01-MAR`, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN DATE(tgl_input_arsip) = '2016-03-02' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `02-MAR`, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN DATE(tgl_input_arsip) = '2016-03-03' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `03-MAR`,
FROM `tabel_arsip`
WHERE `tgl_input_arsip`>='2016-03-01 00:00:00' AND `tgl_input_arsip`<='2016-03-01 23:59:59'
GROUP BY `petugas_input`
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not think for these hard-coded column aliases rather make a query for each `petugas_input` and for each `date` **(within the given date range)** along with the count.

Something like this:

```
SELECT 
`petugas_input`, 
DATE(`tgl_input_arsip`) `date`,
COUNT(*) total
FROM `tabel_arsip`
WHERE `tgl_input_arsip`>='2016-03-01 00:00:00' AND `tgl_input_arsip`<='2016-03-01 23:59:59'
GROUP BY `petugas_input`,`date`;
```

And you will get the following output structure:

---

```
petugas_input           date               total

A                    yyyy-mm-dd             n1
B                    yyyy-mm-dd             n2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
SELECT `petugas_input`, 
COUNT(CASE WHEN DATE(tgl_input_arsip) = '2016-03-01' THEN petugas_input ELSE 0 END) AS `01-MAR`, 
COUNT(CASE WHEN DATE(tgl_input_arsip) = '2016-03-02' THEN petugas_input  ELSE 0 END) AS `02-MAR`, 
COUNT(CASE WHEN DATE(tgl_input_arsip) = '2016-03-03' THEN petugas_input ELSE 0 END) AS `03-MAR`
FROM `tabel_arsip`
WHERE `tgl_input_arsip`>='2016-03-01 00:00:00' AND `tgl_input_arsip`<='2016-03-03 23:59:59'
GROUP BY `petugas_input`;
```

:)